# Clickable H3 Buttons on Moble: How to Handle Accessibility

Tags: html

I have a series of `<h3>` headers with lists of links below them in the footer of my site. On mobile devices, the links collapse and a user can tap the `<h3>` to expand the list.

I'm wondering if using the following is appropriate:

`<h3><button>Section Title</button></h3>`

These headers do not function as buttons on large screened devices. Is this okay to use? How should I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Why use a h3 at all, why not just style the button using a class?

Comment: From a semantic standpoint, you're losing the meaning of an `<h*>` tag...

Comment: @Liam — Because headers are headings.

Comment: @BradChristie — How so? It's still a heading. It's also an interactive control.

Comment: @Quentin Because a button shouldn't be a descendent of a heading.

Comment: @Quentin And a header should not be in the footer.

Comment: @BradChristie — Why not? It is a heading. It is an interactive control. From a semantic point of view, it makes sense. From a standards point of view, it is allowed in HTML.

Comment: @markbernard — It isn't a header (even if the question mistakes it for one), its a heading.

Comment: @Quentin Headings are for use in dividing the content into topics and sub-topics, not for delineating a list of links or buttons.

Comment: @Quentin My mistake. <h1>-<h6> should not appear in the footer of your site.

Comment: @markbernard — A list of links about a particular subject is a section of content about a topic.

Comment: Checked the W3c specs nothing (that I can see) says a h3 can't contain a button and nothing in button says it can't be contained in a h3...so knock yourself out.

Comment: "Interactive Control", to me, implies a `<div>`.

Comment: @markbernard — The HTML 5 specification includes an example of a footer with an `<h1>` in it: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element

Comment: @BradChristie — What's interactive about a div? A div is a generic block element that *you can't focus by default*. Not being able to focus something is a good clue that it isn't supposed to be interactive.

Comment: I can't help but feel that these comments are going off topic?!

Comment: @Quentin: Control: `<div><h1>Heading of control</h1><p>Body of control</p></div>` do with, as you please, the `div>h1` but the h1 shouldn't be the sole item.

Comment: @BradChristie — Nobody suggested it was going to be.

Comment: @Liam Yes, in fact the W3 uses this as an example in the 2nd rule of Aria use: http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second-rule-of-aria-use

Comment: @Vecta: You're citing a draft, be careful. Note the huge disclaimer at the top in green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is appropriate.

- HTML allows button elements inside headings.
- Headings should be used to markup heading content
- Buttons should be used to markup interactive controls
- The (currently draft) notes on using ARIA in HTML include [an example of this](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#secondrule) (thanks to [Vecta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261355/vecta) for spotting that)

The only sticking point, in my mind, is that your content is *conditionally* interactive depending on the screen size.

You might want to address that by using JavaScript to dynamically wrap (and unwrap) the content of the heading with the button based on the window size. (Since the interactivity depends on JS to function in the first place, that shouldn't introduce any support problems).

Comment: Opposite question to the conversation above - "why bother using `<button>` tags at all?" The button seems extraneous to me ... So it's inappropriate, due to ARIA guidelines, to put a conditional event listener directly on the `<h3>` itself to expand/collapse a section?  I've done exactly this, so I'm curious now... Thanks

Comment: @mc01 — See the third bullet point. `<button>` means "Here is something that you can click on / focus and active". A heading doesn't mean that (and without taking other steps, you can't activate it without a pointing device, which means little when its design for mobile only, but is important in the generate case).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. So practically every bit of jQuery on the planet w/a click handler on a non-button-element violates this rule (if the element doesn't also contain the role=button, etc)? That's a lot of incorrect code that would be made more complicated by doing it "right." Makes sense to a point I guess...

Comment: @mc01 — Sadly, lots of pages are built without consideration for accessibility. `tabindex` is important as well, since plenty of people navigate with a keyboard in browsers that don't do much with ARIA.

Comment: Noted & something I'm going to keep in mind for the future. Good link above too. Thanks for the tips!